# HTTP requests using the browser console

Tags: javascript, browser, console

I want to test a download link from the broswer console by using HTTP requests:

So when doing this, the console tells me:

```
get http://wallbase.cc/wallpaper/3023660;
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
get "http://wallbase.cc/wallpaper/3023660";
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

So how do you actually make HTTP calls from the console and viewing the response?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on browser you have to enable persistent network logging. It's available on both *Firefox* and *Chrome*.

Then in the console just execute `window.location = 'http://wallbase.cc/wallpaper/3023660'`.

Check the network log and you'll get your response `header`, `body`, etc.

Comment: ok so using get will not work I guess...How does the REST calls work then from a browser perspective? GET and POST etc

Comment: They perform ajax calls. For different origin it requires jsonp. If you want to test REST search `rest client firefox` or `rest client chrome` on google based on your browser to get a plugin.